# Would a current feedback op-amp work well as a precision ground reference?

Tags: operational-amplifier, feedback, precision, virtual-ground, step-response

I've been looking into precision ground reference circuits to form ±5V rails from a 10V supply for a project I'm working on, and noticed that current feedback (CFB) op-amps have some desirable characteristics (primarily high output current and slew rate). Since I will be using it as a return path for multiple filters and decoupling capacitors, it needs to have a high output current and fast settling time. However, I also need keep the DC level stable across a range of temperatures and under varying loading conditions.

I like the dual-feedback design below that a voltage feedback op-amp, but I also have a few concerns:

- The suggested precision op-amp has a low slew rate. This could be problematic since I am expecting (unavoidable) step changes at the output.
- With the series resistor, I'm afraid that the op-amp will saturate before it can source or sink sufficient current.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fu8pLQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Questions:

- Can I safely route the inverting input of a CFB to a distant part of the board (as a Kelvin connection)?
- Assuming that I can guarantee stability under capacitive loading conditions, am I likely to run into DC drift issues (possibly due to self-heating)? I don't care about the initial DC offset as long as it is *very* stable.
- After setting the feedback resistor, can I still expect to get a high slew rate?

I'm thinking of doing something like this to generate a ground reference using a CFB op-amp (possibly the [LT1206](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1206fb.pdf) or [LT1217](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/lt1217.pdf)):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQMUMO.png)</sup>

Comment: Ahh that recognizable sound of a can of worms being opened. This is not the right route; use a voltage regulator or justify why you can't.

Comment: @Andyaka I thought of that as I was writing the question, but I'm concerned that a regulator would not be able to handle step changes quickly enough. I will need to run some simulations.

Comment: Step changes are handled by the regulators output capacitor as with any type of voltage regulation including using an opamp.